# Background image is stretching

Tags: css

I have a 40x1000 jpg file for my background. My CSS is as follows:

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0 px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(jute_for_web1.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-top:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
div.container
{
    text-align: left;
    border-color: Black;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 768px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color:White;
}
```

This stretches my image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: background images can't be scaled through CSS, so the problem might be something different than what you think.  So in this case if you can provide a link to an example page with the problem then I bet someone will be more likely to find a solution for you

Comment: Which browser are you using? Your code seems to work as intended (the image is repeated the entire width of the browser) in Firefox 3.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

it does not stretch your image..

You just place the `.container` on top of the background image, and since you have `background-color:white` on the container, the image at the body does not get displayed..

tell us what you want to do exactly and we can help more ..

Comment: But the repeated background image will be visible outside the container.

Comment: @Gert, The container is rather large, and most likely hides most of the backgorund.. i think that is why he believes the image gets stretched.. because he only sees a small part of it ..

Answer (score 0):

Some of your HTML may be helpful. In this example, the image appeared correctly. (I made an image using the same name.)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                margin: 0px;
                padding:0 px;
                text-align: center;
                background-image: url(jute_for_web1.jpg) ;
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                border-top:0px;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
            }
            div.container
            {
                text-align: left;
                border-color: Black;
                border-width: 0px;
                border-style: solid;
                width: 1000px;
                height: 768px;
                margin: 5px auto;
                background-color:White;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            Hello World!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to upload an image here so that I can show you what I see?

Comment: This is the image:

http://yfrog.com/jk1d6j

and it renders as:

http://yfrog.com/j5fbqp